# Integral Derivation of kinematics formula

Tags: calculus, integration, kinematics

The following is part of a derivation of the formula $v=v_0 + at$:
$$dv=a\ dt$$
$$\int dv=a \int dt$$
$$ v=at+C$$
Since, a C appears on the right side on integrating $dt$ why doesn't it appear on integrating $dv$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually is a constant that appears when integrating $dv$, it just gets "absorbed" into $C$ in the final expression:

\begin{align*}
    dv &= a\text{ }dt \\
    \int dv &= \int a\text{ }dt \\
    v + c_1 &= at + c_2 \\
    v &= at + (c_2 - c_1) \\
\end{align*}

Since $c_2$ and $c_1$ are just numbers, we can call the difference $c_2 - c_1$ as $C$ to get:
$$ v = at + C $$

Comment: Thank you. However, when you integrate $dv$ how does it turn into $v$

Comment: @uddhavsaikia If $a \in \mathbb R$ (i.e. if $a$ is a constant), then $\int a dx = ax + c$.  When you write $\int dv$, you are essentially integrating the constant, $1$ with respect to $v$.  So, you have $\int 1 dv = 1v + c$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int dv=a\int dt\implies v+c_0=at+c_1\implies v=at+c_1-c_0=at+c_2.$$